# How to close Youtube ads on video automatically?

Tags: html, youtube

This is about the ads that appears on the bottom of the YouTube video screen when a video starts playing for the first time. We can manually close the video by clicking the Close button on the upper right corner of the ad. Is there anyway to write a script or small piece of program for the browser to automatically close if any ad appears, when its browsing YouTube. 
(I thought it would be interesting if we could do that)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Having used YouTube API quite a bit over the years, I've tried to achieve what you are asking without any success.

Unfortunately, there is no way to close overlay ads automatically. This Google forum post confirms it: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/qG733WIH6yE

> It can't be clicked away [advert] because those mouse events are handled internally and cant be managed in the parent application. The parent application obviously has mouse events over the video screen to manage pause / play functionality.

Comment: Yes, your point is correct. The mouse events cannot be handled by the parent application, so we can't create the ad close event automatically. Is there anyway we can block the data of the advertisement from loading, (using a flash script - just a wild guess) then no ad will be displayed. If you could change the width and height of the frame, even that's a start! Thanks a lot sbhomra for your reply, much appreciated.

Comment: Flash scripting is a little out of my remit. But I don't think there is a way to completely remove ads.

If a video has Google ads, then it will have Google ads anywhere that video is embedded and vice versa.

It isn't something you have the option of turning on or off. It all comes down to the video owner and whether they have disabled the option to show Google Ads.

Comment: Yes logically they won't provide an option to block the ad. My intention is to intelligently prepare the browser to filter the content, because I believe web3.0 is not created but converted.

Comment: Instead of "blocking" the view, you may be able to run a click event http://api.jquery.com/trigger/